# Calculating and displaying the result depending on the score

Tags: javascript

In the following JavaScript code you answer both questions and then you will get a specific answer based on your score.

Let's say, you choose Yes a lot for the first question and Chocolate for the second question, you will score 8 points and instead of displaying the number 8 I would like to display a comment. That's why I have created an `if` loop, but for some reason the javascript code is displaying nothing, any suggestions for a solutions?

By the way you can find the code in the following link:

http://jsfiddle.net/9N5ZV/

```
    if (totalScore <=2) {
    calculate = healthy;
 } else if (totalScore >= 3 && totalScore <= 6) {
    calculate = average;
 } else {
    calculate = unhealthy;
 }
```

Comment: `totalScore =<6` should be `totalScore <=6`. Also, you can't have two elses for one if.

Comment: and dont call it an 'if loop' :) its not a loop but a branch

Comment: @Roland Jansen, thank you very much but it is now just displaying the score, I wish that it displays the message saved in var unhealthy = 'Unhealthy'; so instead of displaying 8 it should display Unhealthy. I am not too sure why my loop isnot working.

Comment: `if` and `else` are control flow statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition syntax is wrong, and you use variables out of scope.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9N5ZV/3/)

```
function getTotal()
{
    var totalScore = getScoreCake() + getScoreChoco();
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 
       //"Your total score is: "+totalScore;
       getComment(totalScore);
}
function getComment(score)
{
    if (score <=2)
        return healthy;
    else if(score >= 3 && score <=6)
        return average;
    else
        return unhealthy;
}
```

Comment: thank you very very much (also thank you everyone who suggested a result), demo works perfectly :)

Answer (score 2):

You need an `else if`

```
if (totalScore <=2) {
    calculate = healthy;
 } else if (totalScore >= 3 && totalScore <= 6) {
    calculate = average;
 } else {
    calculate = unhealthy;
 }
```

Also, use the console! You'll see:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

This was due to the `else (expr)` clause, it's `else if`

Answer (score 1):

You conditional statement has errors.  Should be:

```
if (totalScore <= 2) {
   calculate = healthy;
} else if (totalScore >= 3 && totalScore <= 6) {
   calculate = average;
} else {
   calculate = unhealthy;
}
```

Here is an updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9N5ZV/2/).

EDIT:

You are not calling getComment function.  Try the one below to see how you can output the string.

http://jsfiddle.net/9N5ZV/5/

Comment: thank you very much, but it is now just displaying the score, I wish that it displays the message saved in var unhealthy = 'Unhealthy'; so instead of displaying 8 it should display Unhealthy. I am not too sure why my loop isnot working.